# Store Median, SD and N for a Variable

Tags: r, stata

I  have a `crosstable` where I can see the `Median`, `N`, `SD` and so on of Variable `A`(Workload) depending on Variable `B`(Study Program). (first two lines of code below)

[image: here]

Now I want to store the `N`, `Median` and `SD` from Variable `A` to create a graph.

In Stata, I did it like this, but now I want to do the same in R but I don't know how.

Following you can see the code from Stata:

```
sum Q_59953122 if Q_59953156==3
```

Which I wrote in R like this:

```
tapply(Workload_FSS18$Q_59953122, Workload_FSS18$Q_59953156, describe)
sca N_Q_59953122_Q_59953156bpsy = round(r(N), 0.01) //N-Wert speichern
sca median_Q_59953122_Q_59953156bpsy = round(r(p50), 0.01) //Median speichern
sca sd_Q_59953122_Q_59953156bpsy = round(r(sd), 0.01) // SD speichern
```

How can I store these scalars?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your array of variables:

```
v = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Then

```
n = length(v) # number of observations
sd = sd(v) # standard deviation
median = median(v)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help and answer! 
I solved the problem and find the solution.

Comment: Great! You can accept the answer if you feel that it was the help you needed. This way you can help others with the same problem by indicating that your problem was solved.